# Can anyone help me how to convert 100mV AC to 1.5V DC without using any external power supplies

Tags: rectifier, converter

I am looking for a CMOS circuit that will help me to convert 100mV of AC to DC and that DC should boosted to 1.5V.
Firstly can anyone suggest me a CMOS circuit to convert 100mV of AC to DC. And DC to DC boosting is 2nd phase of my circuit.

Comment: When you say "without using any external power supplies", do you mean this circuit needs to get its power from the 100 mV AC?

Comment: Why does it need to be a CMOS circuit?

Comment: You'd be hard pressed to find anything transistorized that runs off 600mV, let alone 100mV. Even for AC the only thing I can think of is a transformer. I feel like this question is an XY question.

Comment: Since you're starting with AC, do the boost first (microphone transformer?) and then rectify. What's the AC frequency? How much power are we talking about?

Comment: 12:1 stepup transformer would be a good first step, if the AC supply can supply enough current. How much can it supply?

Comment: When you query Analog Devices (Linear Technology) for Energy Harvesting (know they have chips for that...) https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11503#/ , you see that for a DC to DC harvesting a minimum Voltage of 1,92V is needed. So you need to convert your 100mV to 2.5-3.2V - you will loose some voltage for the rectification, and then I guess a simple zener diode + transistor will do the job for 1,5V - no need for more advanced silicon

Comment: To get any sort of practical answer you're going to need to explain what the original source and the load are.  Dave Tweed is right that on the surface it would make sense to go through a transformer first, but the whole idea of this seems like something unlikely to work unless the details are very favorable: transforming the voltage/current ratio is one thing, but **there has to be more power available on the input side than needed on the output.**

Answer (score 1):

> *Firstly can anyone suggest me a CMOS circuit to convert 100 mV of AC to
> DC. And DC to DC boosting is 2nd phase of my circuit.*

Wrong order - boost the 100 mV AC to something like a couple of volts AC using a step-up transformer then rectify to DC.

Wrong tech - it doesn't need CMOS to do this. Regular silicon diodes will rectify the upgraded AC signal to produce a couple of volts of DC then a fairly average DC-to-DC converter can take it from there (CMOS or otherwise).